# Error when trying to make file in stdlib.h "_wtoi64 and others not declared in this scope" using MinGW64 & CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, std, mingw-w64

So I tried building a project written on OSX. I'm on windows right now.
I am using CMake and MinGW 64bit.

"cmake -G MinGW "Makefiles"" works fine but when I try to use "mingw32-make" it results in this:

```
Scanning dependencies of target iDemo
[ 16%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/iDemo.dir/src/Example.cpp.obj
[ 33%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/iDemo.dir/src/DemoObject.cpp.obj
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/iDemo.dir/src/iDemo.cpp.obj
[ 66%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/iDemo.dir/src/iDemoProcess.cpp.obj
[ 83%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/iDemo.dir/src/Transform.cpp.obj
Linking CXX static library lib\libiDemo.a
[ 83%] Built target iDemo
Scanning dependencies of target iDemo
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/iDemo.dir/tools/iDemo.cpp.obj
In file included from D:/MinGW/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/assert.h:17:0,

                 from D:/opencv/opencv/sources/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/types_c.h:55,
                 from D:/opencv/opencv/sources/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/core_c.h:47,
                 from D:/opencv/opencv/sources/include/opencv/cv.h:63,
                 from D:\Stuff\code\tools\iDemo.cpp:3:
D:/MinGW/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/stdlib.h: In function 'long long int wtoll(const wchar_t*)':
D:/MinGW/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/stdlib.h:653:100: error: '_wtoi64' was not declared in this scope
   __MINGW_EXTENSION __CRT_INLINE long long  __cdecl wtoll (const wchar_t * _w) { return _wtoi64 (_w); }

                    ^
D:/MinGW/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/stdlib.h: In function 'wchar_t* lltow(long long int, wchar_t*, int)':
D:/MinGW/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/stdlib.h:654:122: error: '_i64tow' was not declared in this scope
   __MINGW_EXTENSION __CRT_INLINE wchar_t *__cdecl lltow (long long _n, wchar_t* _w, int _i) { return _i64tow (_n, _w, _i); }

                                          ^
D:/MinGW/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/stdlib.h: In function 'wchar_t* ulltow(long long unsigned int, wchar_t*, int)':
D:/MinGW/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/stdlib.h:655:133: error: '_ui64tow' was not declared in this scope
   __MINGW_EXTENSION __CRT_INLINE wchar_t *__cdecl ulltow (unsigned long long _n, wchar_t * _w, int _i) { return _ui64tow (_n, _w, _i); }

                                                     ^
CMakeFiles\iDemo.dir\build.make:54: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/iDemo.dir/tools/iDemo.cpp.obj' failed
mingw32-make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/iDemo.dir/tools/iDemo.cpp.obj] Error 1
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:94: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/iDemo.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/iDemo.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:116: recipe for target 'all' failed
mingw32-make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Now the lines in stdlib.h that seem to cause this problem are:

```
#ifndef __CRT__NO_INLINE
  __MINGW_EXTENSION __CRT_INLINE long long  __cdecl atoll (const char * _c) { return _atoi64 (_c); }
  __MINGW_EXTENSION __CRT_INLINE char *__cdecl lltoa (long long _n, char * _c, int _i) { return _i64toa (_n, _c, _i); }
  __MINGW_EXTENSION __CRT_INLINE char *__cdecl ulltoa (unsigned long long _n, char * _c, int _i) { return _ui64toa (_n, _c, _i); }
  __MINGW_EXTENSION __CRT_INLINE long long  __cdecl wtoll (const wchar_t * _w) { return _wtoi64 (_w); }
  __MINGW_EXTENSION __CRT_INLINE wchar_t *__cdecl lltow (long long _n, wchar_t * _w, int _i) { return _i64tow (_n, _w, _i); }
  __MINGW_EXTENSION __CRT_INLINE wchar_t *__cdecl ulltow (unsigned long long _n, wchar_t * _w, int _i) { return _ui64tow (_n, _w, _i); }
#endif /* !__CRT__NO_INLINE */
```

Does anyone have an idea what might be causing this? Maybe even had the same error?
How/Where should _wtoi64 (and the 2 other missing ones) be declared etc? How can I do it myself?

The only other lines in stdlib.h I found are these

```
  __MINGW_EXTENSION _CRTIMP wchar_t *__cdecl _i64tow(__int64 _Val,wchar_t *_DstBuf,int _Radix) __MINGW_ATTRIB_DEPRECATED_SEC_WARN;
  __MINGW_EXTENSION _CRTIMP wchar_t *__cdecl _ui64tow(unsigned __int64 _Val,wchar_t *_DstBuf,int _Radix) __MINGW_ATTRIB_DEPRECATED_SEC_WARN;
  __MINGW_EXTENSION _CRTIMP __int64 __cdecl _wtoi64(const wchar_t *_Str);
  __MINGW_EXTENSION _CRTIMP __int64 __cdecl _wtoi64_l(const wchar_t *_Str,_locale_t _Locale);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end it was some stupid cross-compiler error.
I had to change the order of the includes in "iDemo.cpp":

it was

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <highgui.h>
#include <cv.h>
```

But **cv.h had to be included before everything else** for me.
For him it works fine with the order it had before...